# Print current UTC datetime with special format

Tags: python, datetime, python-2.6, datetime-format

Pretty simple, but I'm a python newbie. I'm trying to print the current UTC date AND time with special format:

Python 2.6.6

```
import datetime, time
print time.strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y", datetime.datetime.utcnow())

TypeError: argument must be 9-item sequence, not datetime.datetime
```

Comment: `time` module is not required. Simply use `datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")` can solve your problem already.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`time.strftime()` only takes [`time.struct_time`-like *time tuples*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.struct_time), not `datetime` objects.

Use the [`datetime.strftime()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strftime) instead:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
'Sat Oct 04 13:00:36  2014'
```

but note that in Python 2.6 no timezone objects are included so nothing is printed for the `%Z`; the object returned by `datetime.datetime.utcnow()` is *naive* (has no timezone object associated with it).

Since you are using `utcnow()`, just include the timezone manually:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S UTC %Y")
'Sat Oct 04 13:00:36 UTC 2014'
```

Answer (score 3):

`utcnow()` returns an object; you should call `.strftime` on that object:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow()
datetime.datetime(2014, 10, 4, 13, 0, 2, 749890)
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
'Sat Oct 04 13:00:16  2014'
```

or, pass the object as the *first* argument of `datetime.datetime.strftime`:

```
>>> type(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
<class 'datetime.datetime'>
>>> datetime.datetime.strftime(datetime.datetime.utcnow(), "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y")
'Sat Oct 04 13:00:16  2014'
```

Answer (score 2):

To print the current time in UTC without changing the format string, you could [define UTC tzinfo class yourself based on the example from datetime documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo.fromutc):

```
from datetime import tzinfo, timedelta, datetime

ZERO = timedelta(0)

class UTC(tzinfo):

    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return ZERO

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "UTC"

    def dst(self, dt):
        return ZERO


utc = UTC()

# print the current time in UTC
print(datetime.now(utc).strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"))
# -> Mon Oct 13 01:27:53 UTC 2014
```

`timezone` class is included in Python since 3.2:

```
from datetime import timezone 
print(datetime.now(timezone.utc).strftime("%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Z %Y"))
# -> Mon Oct 13 01:27:53 UTC+00:00 2014
```