# String formatting of utcnow

Tags: python

Using `utcnow()` I get the following:

```
>>> str(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
'2018-12-07 20:44:11.158487'
```

How would I format this as the following string:

```
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
2018-12-07T20:44:11
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print current UTC datetime with special format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193065/print-current-utc-datetime-with-special-format)

Comment: @mkrieger1 or maybe it isn't special?...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `isoformat()`:

```
t = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
t.isoformat()
> '2018-12-07T20:47:31.645578'
t.isoformat(timespec='seconds')
> '2018-12-07T20:47:31'
```

Comment: thanks, this was really what I was looking for. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
'2018-12-07T20:54:09'
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: What are you curious about?

Comment: Just like, explain how strftime works or link the documentation.

Comment: strftime is often used to convert date types to string type. For detailed information: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime

Answer (score 0):

I won't accept my answer, but there are a few ways to do this. One is the duplicate way mentioned above the other is using the standard `isoformat`.

First, you can reference [Print current UTC datetime with special format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26193065/print-current-utc-datetime-with-special-format) (listed as the duplicate in the question) to use a specific format.

In your specific case it would be:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.utcnow().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
'2018-12-07T20:51:53'
```

The other option would be to use the more standard `t.isoformat()`, as mentioned by shx2. This gives fractional sections, but would be easy to fix that in one of the following two ways:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().replace(microsecond=0).isoformat()
'2018-12-07T12:53:05'

>>>t.isoformat().split('.')[0]
'2018-12-07T20:49:57'
```

Comment: Please see my updated answer. The correct way to remove microseconds is using timespec.

Comment: @shx2 -- I think that's only valid in python3.6+ or so. When I try it using python2.7 it says invalid.