# Timezone: Is there a way to print GMT (Greenwich Mean Time) with datetime in Python?

Tags: python, datetime, timezone, python-datetime

The code works fine so far. I just included it for reference.

```
import datetime

#prints current local datetime with a time zone of none
dt_today = datetime.datetime.today()
# gives option to introduce a timezone
dt_now = datetime.datetime.now()
# utcnow does not signify a timezone-aware datetime
# instead it offers utc info set to now but tcinfo still set to none
dt_utcnow = datetime.datetime.utcnow()

print(dt_today)

print(dt_now)

print(dt_utcnow)

print(dt_utcnow.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'))
```

I tried the obvious:

```
dt_gmt = datetime.datetime.gmt()
```

but that didn't work.

Comment: print(datetime.datetime.utcnow()) works for me, unless I'm misunderstanding what you want to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`help(datetime)` led to the datetime part of python's library which clarified that `gmtime` and `strftime`  turned out to be what I was looking for:

```
import time

print("\nGMT: "+time.strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z", time.gmtime())) 
print("Local: "+strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %p %Z\n"))
```

Comment: the `%Z` in the first print statement (GMT) doesn't work correctly for me; it puts out my local time zone name without DST adjustment (CET, while currently it's still CEST)! weird... I suggest to remove `%Z` here. Also, you should clean up your imports for readability; either import the module (`import time`) or specific classes/methods, not a mix of both.

Comment: works great for me but i'll try your way. Could this possibly be because I'm in GMT?

Comment: "*Could this possibly be because I'm in GMT?*" - could be, yes. Behavior of `%Z` depends on your OS time zone configuration, so results can differ. Btw. it should be `time.strftime(...` in your second print statement ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `datetime.utcnow()`, try `datetime.now(timezone.utc)` as mentioned in
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26331752/10237506).

Example below:

```py
import datetime

#prints current local datetime with a time zone of none
dt_today = datetime.datetime.today()
# gives option to introduce a timezone
dt_now = datetime.datetime.now()
# utcnow does not signify a timezone-aware datetime
# instead it offers utc info set to now but tcinfo still set to none
dt_utcnow = datetime.datetime.now(datetime.timezone.utc)

print(dt_now)

print(dt_utcnow)
print(dt_utcnow.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f %Z'))
```

Output:

```
2021-10-28 19:13:35.069610
2021-10-28 23:13:35.069610+00:00
2021-10-28 23:13:35.069610 UTC
```

Alternate approach, if you really want to include "GMT" instead:

```py
print(dt_utcnow.isoformat().replace("+00:00", " GMT"))
```

Prints: `2021-10-28T23:18:35.637448 GMT`

Comment: I'm in the UK so was trying for GMT (as per the question) but utcnow works fine. Thanx

Comment: Ah, I see. No worries, glad you were able to get it working!